# How to get current index of a PrimeFaces carousel?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a PrimeFaces carousel in which I would like to display an editable inputTextArea. Unfortunately it seems p:carousel has no attribute to get the current index, like rowIndexVar in p:dataGrid.

What are other solutions for rendering only the current inputTextarea ?

```
        <p:carousel value="#{infb.infos}" var="info" **rowIndexVar="status"** numVisible="2" >
                ......
                        <p:inputTextarea value="#{infb.textArea1}" rendered="#{status == 0 and infb.displayEditor}" />
                        <p:inputTextarea value="#{infb.textArea2}" rendered="#{status == 1 and infb.displayEditor}" />
                        <p:inputTextarea value="#{infb.textArea3}" rendered="#{status == 2 and infb.displayEditor}" />
                        <p:inputTextarea value="#{infb.textArea4}" rendered="#{status == 3 and infb.displayEditor}" />
                        <h:panelGrid rendered="#{infb.displayEditor}" columns="2">
                            <p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{infb.modifyInfoText(info)}" />
                            <p:commandButton value="Cancel" action="#{infb.cancelModifyInfoText(info)}"/>  
                        </h:panelGrid>
                 .....
        </p:carousel>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<p:carousel>` implements [`UIData`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIData.html) (like `<p:dataTable>`, `<p:dataGrid>`, etc). That component class has a [`rowIndex`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIData.html#getRowIndex--) property. You could just grab it directly.

First bind the `<p:carousel>` component to an unique variable name in EL ([absolutely don't bind it to a bean property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911158)!):

```
<p:carousel binding="#{carousel}" ...>
```

The component instance will elsewhere in same page be available via `#{carousel}`. You can then just access its `rowIndex` property like so `#{carousel.rowIndex}`.

```
<p:carousel binding="#{carousel}" ...>
    <p:inputTextarea ... rendered="#{carousel.rowIndex eq 0}" />
    <p:inputTextarea ... rendered="#{carousel.rowIndex eq 1}" />
    <p:inputTextarea ... rendered="#{carousel.rowIndex eq 2}" />
    <p:inputTextarea ... rendered="#{carousel.rowIndex eq 3}" />
    ...
</p:carousel>
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, this is [fishy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). Why not just binding the textarea value to the currently iterated row instead of to the bean?

```
<p:carousel ... var="item">
    <p:inputTextarea value="#{item.text}" />
    ...
</p:carousel>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems the attribute binding is not defined any more in the component carousel in recent versions of primefaces. I am using primefaces 5.3. Concerning your 2nd suggestion, I have to modify the textarea value.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. Are you talking about false errors/warnings emitted by the editor you're using which prevented you from actually trying to run the code? Just ignore'n'run it and update/replace the code editor. As to modifying the textarea value, it's still possible that way, so I'm not understanding the problem here either.

Comment: Actually it works ! Yes, I was talking about the NetBeans error. Why is there no binding attribute in the Carousel class ? http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/5.3/   There is a "bindings" inherited attribute, but no "binding".

Comment: For the second part, I thought every modified value had to be saved in a managed bean property ?

Comment: 1) Documentary/IDE bug. 2) It's already a managed bean property. No need to duplicate/flatten/expand it.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't see things like that. Thanks a lot